# how to get xml html after transpose and databind()

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, data-binding, transpose

I have some code that uses xsl and xml.
The Xml control is on the design page.
The xml control id is xmlApplication
The xmlstring is generated and xsl has the format with all the tables and cells etc.
Here is a part of thecode of a page which generates the final product which shows the xml in a certain format.

```
xmlApplication.Document = xmlDoc;
xmlApplication.Transform = transApp;
xmlApplication.DataBind();
```

I am guessing after xmlApplication.Databind(), xmlApplication will be converted into something that can be put inside  .
Is it possible to grab as a string?

Please let me know if I have a wrong idea abut this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.logiclabz.com/c/net-c-function-to-convert-xml-document-into-html-string-using-xslt.aspx